# How to insert a column/row of ones into a matrix?

Tags: octave

Suppose that we have  a 3x3 matrix like

```
b = 2 * eye(3);
ans =

2   0   0
0   2   0
0   0   2
```

and I want to a 3x4 matrix like

```
1   2   0   0
1   0   2   0
1   0   0   2
```

What is the best way to get it?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

An easy inline way to do this is:

`b = [ones(size(b, 1), 1) b];`

Comment: Octave has `rows()`, if you don't care about Matlab such as myself.

Comment: `rows' is a built-in function

 -- Built-in Function:  rows (A)
     Return the number of rows of A.

Comment: To add a row :
b = [ ones(1,columns(b)) ; b]

Comment: To add a column: c = [ ones(rows(c),1) , c ]

Answer (score 23):

In GNU Octave:

Concatenate two matrices together horizontally: separate the matrices by a Space,
and enclose the result in square brackets:

```
X = [ones(rows(X), 1) X];
```

Simpler examples:
Glue on one number (add a horizontal "Column" element with a Comma):

```
octave:1> [[3,4,5],8]
ans =
   3   4   5   8
```

Glue on another matrix horizontally (as additional Columns) by using a Comma:

```
octave:2> [[3,4,5],[7,8,9]]
ans = 
   3   4   5   7   8   9
```

Glue on another matrix vertically (as additional Rows) by using a Semicolon:

```
octave:3> [[3,4,5];[7,8,9]]
ans =
   3   4   5
   7   8   9
```

Answer (score 7):

One way to do it is:

```
function [result] = prependOnes(matrix)
  result = [ones(rows(matrix),1) matrix];
end

prependOnes(b)
```

Answer (score 3):

The function [padarray](http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/function/padarray.html) (from the [image package](http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/index.html)) was designed to do exactly that.

```
octave> b = 2 * eye (3)
b =

Diagonal Matrix

   2   0   0
   0   2   0
   0   0   2

octave> padarray (b, [0 1], 1, "pre")
ans =

   1   2   0   0
   1   0   2   0
   1   0   0   2
```

The functions reads *pre pad the variable `b` with 0 rows and 1 column*. The function allows for a big flexibility when padding matrices but may be overkill for really simple stuff.

Comment: could not find the function? Is this an built-in or user defined?

Comment: @BhupeshPant it's on the image package. Run `pkg list` to see if it's installed, and then `pkg load image` to load it.

Answer (score 3):

I Would like to point out that `[A B]` actually creates a **new matrix** as oppose to **inserting**, which should be obvious from its syntactic construction. But I see a lot of place use the word *append* or *insert* that I wonder whether octave does any clever thing behind, so I run a test

```
function testAppend(repeat)

profile off;
profile on; 
testAdd(repeat);
testAssign(repeat);
profile off;
data = profile('info');
profshow(data, 5); 

end

function testAdd(repeat)
for i = 1:repeat
    A = ones(100, 1); 
    B = ones(100, 1); 
    for j = 1:10000
        A = [A B]; 
    end 
end
end

function testAssign(repeat)
for i = 1:repeat
    B = ones(100, 1); 
    A = zeros(100, 10000);
    for j = 2:10001
        A(:, j) = B;
    end 
end
end
```

and here is the result

```
octave:1> testAppend(1)
   #              Function Attr     Time (s)        Calls
---------------------------------------------------------
   1    testAppend>testAdd             9.454            1
   3 testAppend>testAssign             0.023            1
   4                 zeros             0.001            1
   5               profile             0.000            1
   2                  ones             0.000            3
```

So if you need to continuously grow your matrix, create the target matrix first then assign value to it. Or implement something like resizing-matrix if you don't know the ultimate dimension in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The b matrix is defined as below

```
>> b = [1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9]
b =

   1   2   3
   4   5   6
   7   8   9
```

creating a new matrix by adding a new column of 1s as below

```
>> [ones(size(b), 1) b]
ans =

   1   1   2   3
   1   4   5   6
   1   7   8   9
```

Creating a new matrix by adding a new row of 1s as below

```
>> [ones(size(b)(2), 1)';b]
ans =

   1   1   1
   1   2   3
   4   5   6
   7   8   9
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a 3x3 matrix like

```
b = 2 * eye(3)
ans =

2   0   0
0   2   0
0   0   2
```

You can add a column of ones as below and recieve new 4x3 matrix

```
[ones(size(b, 1), 1) b]
ans =

1   2   0   0
1   0   2   0
1   0   0   2
```

You can add a row of ones as below and recieve new 3x4 matrix

```
[ones(1,size(b, 2)); b]
ans =

1   1   1
2   0   0
0   2   0
0   0   2
```